# Python Egg Extraction Error When Trying to Use pyproj in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyproj

I have pyproj installed in my conda environment on my local machine (MacBook Pro).  Everything works properly.  I am able to use pyproj within the pyspark installation on my local machine.  However, I mainly work on a Linux machine I SSH to and I have shipped my conda environment from that Linux machine to an HDFS cluster so that I can use pyproj (and pyspark) on a large dataset.

When I try to run the same rdd.map() code on that HDFS cluster in which some pyproj stuff is inside the .map(), I get the following error:

```
ExtractionError: (ExtractionError("Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.cache'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  /home/.cache/Python-Eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.
",).
```

The '/home/.cache/Python-Eggs' is a directory on the Linux machine I SSH to, not in HDFS, nor my local machine (MacBook Pro).

How can I debug this?

Comment: Does your login account have a directory within /home? If so try setting "export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/home/<<username>>/.cache/Python-Eggs. You'll need to create this directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I will try when I get home.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Tried the suggestion, but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following configuration:

```
pyspark/spark-submit 
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="./.python-eggs/" 
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_DIR="./.python-eggs/" 
--conf spark.driverEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="./.python-eggs/" 
--conf spark.driverEnv.PYTHON_EGG_DIR="./.python-eggs/"
```